# Advanced permalinks structure

Tags: categories, permalinks, tags

I would like to get this:

```
mysite.com/category/tag/
```

example:

```
mysite.com/news/sports/
```

News is a CATEGORY and sports is a TAG

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: And on this page /news/sports/, the only posts that would show would be posts **categorized news** and **tagged sports?**

Comment: Yes. It is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is practically setup to support this out of the box. You can go to `mysite.com/?category_name=news&tag=sports` to see the magic happen. All we need to do here is match a permalink structure to this existing URI, and WP makes this unreasonably easy.

In your theme's functions.php file, add:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_88059_add_rewrites' );
function wpse_88059_add_rewrites() {
    add_permastruct( 'category_tags', '%category%/%post_tag%', array( 'walk_dirs' => false ) );
}
```

Now be sure to reload your rewrite rules by going to Settings -> Permalinks and clicking "Save Changes" (you don't have to actually change anything) and you're done!

## Caveats

This is going to add some "wildcard" rewrite rules which can easily interfere with others, depending on your site's content, permalink structure, etc. For instance, let's say your permalink structure is "Day and name", which adds rules for year/month archive pages like /2013/02/. **These links will no longer work** because WordPress is expecting to find a category of "2013" and a tag of "02".

This is why WordPress typically prefixes elements, like /category/news/. Depending on your needs, these conflicts may be a dealbreaker or may be moot, that's up to you and your project. If you want to add a static prefix (or suffix), you could change `%category%/%post_tag%` to something like `archives/%category%/%post_tag%` to get URIs like /archives/news/sports/ or `%category%/%post_tag%/articles` to get URIs like /news/sports/articles/.

Comment: It doesn't work when I go into a post. 
By other hand, If I want mysite.com/news/2010, how can I get it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a static prefix or suffix as I outlined above.

Comment: It doesn't work when I go into a post, because is expecting to find a tag with the title of the post :(

Comment: If your current permalink structure is %category%/%postname%, then what you're asking in your question fundamentally isn't going to work for you.

Comment: My structure is %category%/%postname%. Is not a way to get it?

Comment: You'll need to either use a different permalink structure like day and name, or use a static prefix (or suffix) as I detailed in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is there a way to translate the static prefix or suffix. If my site is in english, I will use the prefix "articles" and If my site is in german I will use "artikel".

Comment: That's a separate question with a large variety of answers. I'd suggest Googling that, or reaching out to your translation plugin's authors. Best of luck!